# multiple group_by with join and order by

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

i have three tables

buyer

b_id and b_name

product

p_id, p_status, p_cat

bid

bid_id, bid_amount, fkb_id,  fkp_id (foreign key for buyer and product table )

buyers can  do many bids on same products
**i want to fetch all records for each product having unique bid_amount in desc**

i try this

```
     $this->db->distinct();

     $this->db->from('bid'); 

     $this->db->join('product','product.p_id=bid.fkp_id');

     $this->db->join('buyer','buyer.b_id=bid.fkb_id');

     $this->db->where('product.p_status','close');

     $this->db->where('product.p_cat','diamond');

     $res = $this->db->get();

     $res_data = $res->result();

     return $res_data;
```

This return all products but not unique fkb_id (buyer i.e bidder id in this case)

Answer (score 0):

Use Group by at the end of the query...

```
 $this->db->group_by('column_name');
```

Answer (score 0):

try like this 
$this->db->max('bid_amount');
$this->db->group_by('fkb_id');